# percorrer listas int em python pulando numeros consecutivos

Tags: python-3.x

Gente, estou tentando eliminar números consecutivos em uma lista de inteiros. Quando a lista for por exemplo 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9... ele mostrar: 1-3, 5-9
Tentei de diversas maneiras e cheguei nesse codigo:

```
def apresenta(lst):

for i in lst:
    x = i #1
    a = i+1 #2 
    b = i+2 #3
    c = i+3 #4
    d = i+4 #5
    e = i+5 #6
    f = i+6 #7
    g = i+7 #8
    h = i+8 #9
    z = i+9 #10
    j = i+10 #11
    l = i+11 #12
    m = i+12 #13
    if len(lst) > 2:
        while b > x:
            lst.pop(a)
        while d > b:
            lst.pop(a)
        while f > d:
            lst.pop(e)
        while h > f:
            lst.pop(g)
        while j > h:
            lst.pop(z)
    return lst
```

quando testo em apresenta([1,2,3,4])

Ele me diz IndexError: pop index out of range

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Sei que falta muita lógica nesse codigo, mas depois de varias tentativas eu to perdida...

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi sua dúvida, segue o script para fazer o que precisa:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11]

l = list(set(l)) # Remove números duplicados
l.sort() # Ordenar os números

def apresenta(iterable):
  return ','.join(as_range(g) for _, g in groupby(l, key=lambda n, c=count(): n-next(c)))

def as_range(iterable):
    l = list(iterable)
    if len(l) > 1:
        return '{0}-{1}'.format(l[0], l[-1])
    else:
        return '{0}'.format(l[0])


print(apresenta(l))
```

As duas linhas comentadas podem ser utilizadas ou não, dependendo de sua necessidade.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta. O código funciona bem quando temos uma lista pré-definida l = [], mas quero fazer essa nova lista pulando nṹmeros consecutivos para indicar aparição de palavras em um índice, e testei esse código puxando a função em 'apresenta([1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11])' e não funciona, pode me explicar por que?

Comment: Desculpe, talvez o código não ficou tão claro, vou atualizar ele. De qualquer forma se passar a lista direto no lugar do 'g' ali no 'apresenta' ele não funciona mesmo, pois a sequencia é gerada pelo groupby logo a frente.